# How to parse deep XML values with C#

Tags: c#, xml

Working in Visual Studio 2010, .NET v4

I'm a relative newbie to both C# and XML. Using website resources, I was able to work out a fairly simple approach to parsing XML for specific values. However, the XML became increasingly complex, and the method I'm using (sort of a 'navigate via iterations' technique) is starting to look rather absurd, with many nested reader.Read() calls. I'm certain there's a less embarrassing way, but when the only tool you have is a hammer...

So, the question is: What's a neat, clean way to parse the XML (see below), returning a list of all 'action' values, only from an item matching `<item itemkind="Wanted">` and `<phrase>SomeSearchString</phrase>`?

Here is a fragment of the XML:

```
<formats>
  <items>
    <item itemkind="NotWanted">
      <phrase>Not this one</phrase>
      <actions>
        <action>
          <actionkind>SetStyle</actionkind>
          <parameter>Normal</parameter>
        </action>
        <action>
          <actionkind>SetMargins</actionkind>
          <parameter>0.25,0.25,1,4</parameter>
        </action>
      </actions>
    </item>

    <item itemkind="Wanted">
      <phrase>SomeSearchString</phrase>
      <actions>
        <action>
          <actionkind>Action 1</actionkind>
          <parameter>Param 1</parameter>
        </action>
        <action>
          <actionkind>Action 2</actionkind>
          <parameter>Param 2</parameter>
        </action>
        <action>
          <actionkind>Action 3</actionkind>
          <parameter>Param 3</parameter>
        </action>
      </actions>
    </item>
  </items>

  <styles>
    <style stylename="Normal">
      <fontname>Arial</fontname>
      <fontsize>10</fontsize>
      <bold>0</bold>
    </style>
    <style stylename="Heading">
      <fontname>fntame frhead</fontname>
      <fontsize>12</fontsize>
      <bold>1</bold>
    </style>
  </styles>
</formats>
```

And here's the code that I've arrived at. It does work, but, well, see for yourself. Please be gentle:

```
public static List<TAction> GetActionsForPhraseItem(string AFileName, string APhrase)
{
   List<TAction> list = new List<TAction>();
   string xmlactionkind = null;
   string xmlparameter = null;
   string match = null;

   // Search through XML items
   using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(AFileName))
   {
      if (reader.ReadToFollowing("items"))
      {
         while (reader.Read())
         {
            if (reader.ReadToFollowing("item"))
            {
               while (reader.Read())
               {
                  if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.GetAttribute("itemkind") == "Phrase")
                  {
                     if (reader.ReadToFollowing("phrase"))
                     {
                        match = reader.ReadString();
                        if (match == APhrase)
                        {
                           if (reader.ReadToFollowing("actions"))
                           {
                              // Use a subtree to deal with just the aItemKind item actions
                              using (var SubTree = reader.ReadSubtree())
                              {
                                 bool HaveActionKind = false;
                                 bool HaveParameter = false;

                                 while (SubTree.Read())
                                 {
                                    if (SubTree.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && SubTree.Name == "actionkind")
                                    {
                                       xmlactionkind = SubTree.ReadString();
                                       HaveActionKind = true;
                                    }

                                    if (SubTree.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && SubTree.Name == "parameter")
                                    {
                                       xmlparameter = SubTree.ReadString();
                                       HaveParameter = true;
                                    }

                                    if ((HaveActionKind == true) && (HaveParameter == true))
                                    {
                                       TAction action = new TAction()
                                       {
                                          ActionKind = xmlactionkind,
                                          Parameter = xmlparameter
                                       };

                                       list.Add(action);
                                       HaveActionKind = false;
                                       HaveParameter = false;
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
   return list;
}
```

Bearing in mind that I'm new to C#, I suspect that LINQ would be quite useful here, but so far I haven't been able to wrap my brain around it. Trying to learn too many new things at once, I imagine. Thanks in advance for any help (and constructive criticisms).

EDIT: This is the final working code I ended up with. Thanks everyone who responded!

```
public static List<TAction> GetActionsForPhraseItemTWO(string AFileName, string ASearchPhrase)
{
  List<TAction> list = new List<TAction>();
  var itemKind = "Wanted";
  var searchPhrase = ASearchPhrase;
  var doc = XDocument.Load(AFileName);
  var matches = doc.Descendants("item")
    .Where(x => x.Attribute("itemkind") != null &&
       x.Attribute("itemkind").Value == itemKind &&
       x.Descendants("phrase").FirstOrDefault() != null &&
       x.Descendants("phrase").FirstOrDefault().Value == searchPhrase)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Descendants("action"));
  foreach (var temp in matches)
  {
    TAction action = new TAction()
    {
      ActionKind = temp.Element("actionkind").Value.ToString(),
      Parameter = temp.Element("parameter").Value.ToString()
    };
    list.Add(action);
  }
  return list;
}
```

Comment: Unless you *need* to use a reader (which is only really beneficial when a huge amount of data is streamed and full DOM construction is not feasible), I would recommend the [XPath extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351355.aspx) for XDocument (XDocument and related XNode also play well with LINQ and LINQ-like queries). Alternatively, consider mapping to a POCO via [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) (which is much more flexible than DCS here) or similar to get "static typing".

Comment: When you see `}
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }` in your code, it means you're doing something wrong. :)

Comment: @TimothyShields, that's pretty much what prompted me to ask this. When it was only 8 layers deep, I figured, bah, that's fine. But when it hit 13, well, that was a brace too far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq to XML is what you want...  also you want the Actions right?  I don't think any of the other answers give you that...

```
        var itemKind = "Wanted";
        var searchPhrase = "SomeSearchString";
        var doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
        var matches = doc.Descendants("item")
            .Where(x => x.Attribute("itemkind") != null &&
                x.Attribute("itemkind").Value == itemKind &&
                x.Descendants("phrase").FirstOrDefault() != null &&
                x.Descendants("phrase").FirstOrDefault().Value == searchPhrase)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Descendants("action"));
```

Comment: All of the answers were useful, and this one ultimately became the base for my new code. My takeaway from this topic is that there are a lot of ways to skin this particular cat. I'm going to have to spend some time learning the various options, and which situations call for which approach.

Answer (score 4):

```
var node = XDocument.Load(fname)
                    .XPathSelectElement("//item[@itemkind='Wanted']/phrase");
var text = node.Value;
```

Comment: OP is using XMLReader instead of XMLDocument(). Unless memory overhead is a major concern using a XMLDocment and XPatj is definitely easier and my first choice.

Comment: @GaryWalker My answer doesn't use XmlDocument. It's LinqToXml :)

Comment: I *really like* XPath for tasks like this - Linq2Xml (I would argue that XPathSelectElement is not strictly Linq related ;-) is nice and flexible but it lacks the terse descriptive DSL power of XPath which can be used in such cases, as shown.

Comment: I'm using XMLReader only because I stumbled across some sample code for it early on, and it sort of grew out of control. That whole "if you only have a hammer..." situation. I'm not married to it, and would happily scrap the XMLReader code for any of the much better approaches I'm seeing here. Tomorrow, though. Brain is still full tonight.

Answer (score 3):

```
var val = XDocument.Load(filename) // OR  XDocument.Parse(xmlstring)
            .Descendants("item")
            .First(i => i.Attribute("itemkind").Value == "Wanted")
            .Element("phrase")
            .Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a defined XML schema, I would just declare matching classes to represent that data, and use the [XmlSerializer to deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa420a9y.aspx) the XML.

So based on your posted XML, your classes might look like:

```
[XmlType("formats")]
public class Formats
{
    [XmlArray("items")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("styles")]
    public List<Style> Styles { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlAttribute("itemkind")]
    public string ItemKind { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("phrase")]
    public string Phrase { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("actions")]
    public List<Action> Actions { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("action")]
public class Action
{
    [XmlElement("actionkind")]
    public string ActionKind { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("parameter")]
    public string Parameter { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("style")]
public class Style
{
    [XmlAttribute("stylename")]
    public string StyleName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("fontname")]
    public string FontName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("fontsize")]
    public int FontSize { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("bold")]
    public bool Bold { get; set; }
}
```

A sample deserialization code might look like:

```
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Formats));
FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(AFileName, FileMode.Open);
var formats = (Formats)mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);
```

Then searching the data is a simple as iterating through your objects and their properties:

```
List<Action> matchingActions = formats.Items
    .Where(item => item.ItemKind == "Wanted")
    .Where(item => item.Phrase == "SomeSearchString")
    .SelectMany(item => item.Actions)
    .ToList();
```

A good aspect of this is you reduce dependencies on hard-coded string literals that define your XML schema. It becomes very easy to quickly refactor or change the structure of your data without accidentally breaking your application. Also note that it handles several cases of type-parsing for you (for example, the `Style.Bold` property can easily be strongly typed as a `bool` rather than parsed as a "0" or "1" `string`)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [XML Serialization Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx). This allows you to map XML and C# objects back and forth. For some applications, this works quite well. It lets you deal with C# objects almost exclusively, not having to worry about parsing XML bit by bit.

Answer (score -2):

You might want to take a look at the MSDN pages for LINQToXML. [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387044.aspx) for example. Alternatively just search for "LinQ to XML". There are lots of useful articles.